# Drag and Drop function not working within Movie Clip - ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

forgive the sloppy code, it's in the initial stages and thus hasn't been cleaned up much, feel free to suggest some ways I can clean the code or make it more efficient.

I'm building a drag and drop PC building segment as part of an ICT educational flash app, instead of having loads of frames and code all over the timeline I want to have all the different segments as unique movie clips.

Anyway, the code works when I have it in the standard flash timeline, but when I convert the objects to a movie clip and put the code within the movie clip the items are draggable but will not go into their slots, or "dropZones"

Here is my code:

```
import flash.events.MediaEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.Sound;

var draggableObjects:Array = new Array(hdd, wifi, gpu, cpu, ram);

// variables for draggable objects positions
var hdd_x:Number = hdd.x;  
var hdd_y:Number = hdd.y;
var wifi_x:Number = wifi.x;
var wifi_y:Number = wifi.y;
var gpu_x:Number = gpu.x;
var gpu_y:Number = gpu.y; 
var cpu_x:Number = cpu.x;
var cpu_y:Number = cpu.y; 
var ram_x:Number = ram.x;
var ram_y:Number = ram.y; 

// creates event listner for every draggable object and sets them to use      button mode
for each (var object in draggableObjects) {
    object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragObject);
    object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, objectRelease);
    object.buttonMode = true;
}

function dragObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var item:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target);
    item.startDrag();
    var topPos:uint = this.numChildren-1;
    this.setChildIndex(item, topPos);
}

function objectRelease(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    var item:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target); 
    var click:Sound;
    if (item == hdd) {
        var original_x:Number = hdd_x;
        var original_y:Number = hdd_y;
        var dropZone:MovieClip = hddTarget;
    } else if (item == wifi) {
        var original_x:Number = wifi_x;
        var original_y:Number = wifi_y;
        var dropZone:MovieClip = wifiTarget;
    } else if (item == gpu) {
        var original_x:Number = gpu_x;
        var original_y:Number = gpu_y;
        var dropZone:MovieClip = gpuTarget;
    } else if (item == cpu) {
        var original_x:Number = cpu_x;
        var original_y:Number = cpu_y;
        var dropZone:MovieClip = cpuTarget;
    } else if (item == ram) {
        var original_x:Number = ram_x;
        var original_y:Number = ram_y;
        var dropZone:MovieClip = ramTarget;
    } else {
        return;
    }
    item.stopDrag();       
    if (dropZone.hitTestPoint(item.x,item.y)) { 
        click = new clickSound();
        click.play();
        item.x = dropZone.x; 
        item.y = dropZone.y; 
    } else { 
        item.x = original_x;
        item.y = original_y; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Where are your `wifiTarget` and other target items defined? on the same timeline as this code you've posted?

Comment: They were defined within the timeline, but are now defined within the movie clip